# How to disable other options and append values in multiple dropdown with same values in angular js?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, model-view-controller, html-select, angularjs-ng-model

I need 3 dropdown list with same values. 1st dropdown is mandatory to select. The rest 2 is optional

all 3 dropdown lists has same options. If user selects a certain option in dropdown 1, it will be disabled for other dropdowns. After the 3 dropdowns is selected, the selected values will be shown as a text in the same page. This text will be then pushed into db. The db field is selected_option.

I am new to angular and kinda stuck so long in this. What am I missing here? Please help :(

This is in my view

```
          <div class="row form-group">
           Selected:
           Dropdown 1 : <select class="form-control" ng-model="selected_option[0]" 
ng-options="option.value as option.text for option in params">
           </select>
        </div>
        <div class="row form-group">
           Selected:
           Dropdown 2 : <select class="form-control" ng-model="selected_option[1]" 
ng-options="option.value as option.text for option in params">
           </select>
        </div>
        <div class="row form-group">
           Selected:
           Dropdown 3 : <select class="form-control" ng-model="selected_option[2]" 
ng-options="option.value as option.text for option in params">
           </select>
    
    {{ selected_option }}
        </div>
```

This is in my controller

```
 $scope.selected_option = [];
  $scope.params= [
                                {value: "A", text: "A"},
                                {value: "B", text: "B"},
                                 {value: "C", text: "C"},
                               
                            ];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using `ng-options` you can use `ng-repeat` to display all options. And by using `ng-disabled` you can disable few options.

```
<div class="row form-group">
    Selected:
    Dropdown 1 : 
    <select class="form-control" ng-model="selected_option[0]">
        <option ng-repeat="option in params" ng-value="option.value">{{ option.value }}</option> 
    </select>
</div>
<div class="row form-group">
    Selected:
    Dropdown 2 : 
    <select class="form-control" ng-model="selected_option[1]">
        <option ng-repeat="option in params" ng-value="option.value" ng-disabled="option.value == selected_option[0]">{{ option.value }}</option> 
    </select>
</div>
<div class="row form-group">
    Selected:
    Dropdown 3 : 
    <select class="form-control" ng-model="selected_option[2]">
        <option ng-repeat="option in params" ng-value="option.value" ng-disabled="option.value == selected_option[0] || option.value == selected_option[1]">{{ option.value }}</option> 
    </select>
    {{ selected_option }}
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks much! it works! but i face an issue when im saving this values to the db.. Im saving these options at php model, so how can i save if im using only saving first 2 options? selected_option[0] and selected_option[1] ?

Comment: @user6345655 I am not able to understand your problem. Can you please share exact requirement and PHP code.

Comment: Hello! Sorry for the late reply. Pardon me for that question asked above. The code works as expected! :)